# AWS CodePipeline - Deployment to Elastic Beanstalk has taken 18 hours. How do I cancel it?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy

I have a codepipeline that feeds from GitHub into Elastic Beanstalk.   It has currently been deploying for 18 hours and hasn't stopped.   Admittedly, I probably made a mistake with removing an App from a Django project incorrectly, but how do I cancel the Elastic Beanstalk Deployment?

To be honest, I'm not even sure if it is deploying correctly because the EB hasn't updated when I look at it inside Code Pipeline but it is in progress when I look at it outside and the blue wheel is spinning (see pictures).

Can I just remove the database and then redeploy the Django project to re-initiate everything from scratch ?   This isn't a production system, so it isn't critical.

Thanks for your help.

[image: code pipeline outside]
[image: code pipeline inside]

Comment: Amazon CloudFormation could show some useful info too.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy an EB application, it manages a deployment to individual instances on EC-2. If you terminate the application's DB, it will probably have no positive effect. You should try terminating the EC-2 instance(s) of the EB application, or running a re-build of the application.

EB applications can be rebuilt in the console view of the particular application, Actions -> Rebuild environment. The rebuild will wipe the db and re-create the ec2 instances.

Terminating or rebooting an EC-2 instance:

1. Go to Services -> EC -> Instances
2. Check the checkbox of your project's instance
3. Actions -> instance state -> terminate (or reboot)

Answer (score 0):

What is the current status of the EB environment? You need to get the EB environment status to either 'Ready' or 'Terminating/Terminated' to have the CodePipeline worker proceed.

There is a hack to stop the in-progress pipeline. You need to Edit the 'BuildTestinTests' action and rename it to anything else, e.g. 'BuildTestinTests2'. This will make the old action orphan and CodePipeline will think you have never executed 'BuildTestinTests2'. The old orphan action will die in due time and this will allow you to execute the pipeline again from Console.

Answer (score 0):

I tried stopping and terminating the EC2 instances, but unfortunately when they were restarted, the deployment just hung.   I also tried stopping the EC2 instances and then deploying the code via code pipeline, but as soon as I started them up again, it just hung.

Because Django uses migrations, I decided to clean it all up from scratch.   I'm sure this wouldn't be appropriate in a production environment, but I terminated the EB Environment and disabled the code pipeline make my life easy.   I then created a new EB Environment and linked that into the code pipeline.   I also removed and recreated the database so that all migrations are created from scratch.    It might have been a bit of an overkill, but it got things working again.

Thanks for your help.